# error in disabling anonymous authentication in IIS using appcmd

Tags: authentication, iis, appcmd

I am trying to disable anonymous authentication by running this command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Reviewer" /section:anonymousAuthentication /enabled:false
```

I am getting this error:

ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "enabled" to value "false".. Reason: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
. )

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the locking issue by adding `/commit:apphost` at the end.

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Reviewer" /section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /enabled:false /commit:apphost
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, after digging a little bit more on this.
I have an Environment 120+ Servers that have the Default ftp anonymous enabled:

On 2 ways:

- Default Host
- Default FTP site

Here is the way to automate this:

Notes:
This line will remove the Anonymous from the host:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /siteDefaults.ftpServer.security.authentication.anonymousAuthentication.enabled:"False" /commit:apphost
```

This line will remove the Anonymous from the Ftp site

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='default'].ftpServer.security.authentication.anonymousAuthentication.enabled:"False" /commit:apphost
```

Path:
`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>`